# Genre of "Band Take [X]" songs from the "Scythian Lamb" soundtrack

Tags: rock, genre, style

I discovered these songs on the [*Scythian Lamb*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Scythian-Lamb-ORIGINAL-SOUNDTRACK/dp/B0796QHQS4) soundtrack and am pretty curious about them.

See the above link --the songs I'm interested in are all named "Band Take #"

**What genre do these songs fall into?**

Answer (score 1):

It's **Japanese Indie** music. As per this quote:

> A collaborative project initiated by session musician and long
>   standing member of the Japanese indie scene, Ken Takehisa. With 11
>   musicians taking part, the artist sent recordings of not just melodies
>   and chords, but also scrapes, noise and amplifier feedback for
>   everyone to break apart use as the building blocks for the album.

Comment: I also wasn't sure we could label genre and where they come from, too often... but apparently, it's a thing "Italian Rock" "Swedish metal"... Thanks again